# How to make AppBarLayout to completely disappear with windowTranslucentStatus set to true

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-scroll, google-photos

I'm developing an Android app using the new design library. I would like to create a similar scrolling effect that is used in the new [Google Photos app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.photos&hl=en). I would like the AppBarLayout to scroll off of screen completely so that the recycler view would scroll behind the status bar.

I've set windowTranslucentStatus to true in the app's theme. Here's the xml of the main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here's what this looks like when scrolled down:
[image: Toolbar not disappearing completely]

The Toolbar doesn't completely disappear.

Thanks for help!

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if they even used the CoordinatorLayout... I've been stuck on this exact question all day.

Comment: @timothyjc If you find a solution before I do, can you please post it here. And I think you're right yes

Comment: Uploaded my sample project to github in case anyone wants to easily see the issue... https://github.com/timothyjc/TestALot

Comment: any luck on this one?

Comment: @pratsJ Not with AppBarLAyout and Toolbar. I have created a custom toolbar and added some elevation effect to the toolbar when scrolling. It's not the same as I've described above though.

Comment: Anyone has the solution to this? Have been scratching my head for the last few days.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what i used in my application

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was about as close as I could get with the CoordinatorLayout (just playing with the margins on the toolbar)... not close enough imo:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="81dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-28dp"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_headphones_white_24dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I think it will be easier to do it manually...

Do you have any ideas or progress?

Comment: I'm trying to work out something with setting height and margins to coordinator layout. However this is creating new problems. Did you figure it out?

Comment: Some guy on Reddit told me there is a bug and it will be fixed next release of the support design lib. I ended up doing all the animations manually.

Comment: @timothyjc fitsSystemWindows must be on the AppBarLayout too.
And  android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds=true should be there in v-21 styles.xml
This is what I did to make it work.

Comment: @Suleiman. I tried that but it did not work when using a semitransparent status bar for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added fitSystemWindows="false" to CoordinatorLayout and fitSystemWindows="true" to its child - in your case to the RecyclerView. On NavigationView, DrawerLayout, AppBarLayout and Toolbar its "true". I've tried diferent values and then something breaks in my case. Android 5.1.1 and the latest support libraries (23.0.1). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use common pattern of AppBarLayout that comes from the app template when you create an Android project in Android Studio. Just few changes in XML layout and Java code:

XML Layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            />

    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Java Code:

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(toolbar, new OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
        @Override
        public WindowInsetsCompat onApplyWindowInsets(View v, WindowInsetsCompat insets) {
            toolbarContainerLayout.setPadding(0, insets.getSystemWindowInsetTop(), 0, 0);

            return insets;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Add fitsSystemWindows="true" for your AppBarLayout and CoordinatorLayout.

---

Comment: That doesn't make the Toolbar transparent.